# Database access error while starting my docker-compose file

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, cloud

I try to run owncloud in docker, but as a result, after starting in logs of owncloud container, I see a database access error. All connection details are correct.

```
Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'owncloud'@'usr_owncloud_1.usr_default' (using password: YES)
```

The config is taken from the official site:
https://doc.owncloud.com/server/admin_manual/installation/docker/#docker-compose-yaml-file

```
version: '2.1'

volumes:
  files:
    driver: local
  mysql:
    driver: local
  backup:
    driver: local
  redis:
    driver: local

services:
  owncloud:
    image: owncloud/server:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      - OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN=localhost
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_TYPE=mysql
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_NAME=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_USERNAME=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_HOST=db
      - OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_USERNAME=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=123456789Aa
      - OWNCLOUD_MYSQL_UTF8MB4=true
      - OWNCLOUD_REDIS_ENABLED=true
      - OWNCLOUD_REDIS_HOST=redis
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - files:/mnt/data

  db:
    image: webhippie/mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - MARIADB_USERNAME=owncloud
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=owncloud
      - MARIADB_MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET=128M
      - MARIADB_INNODB_LOG_FILE_SIZE=64M
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - backup:/var/lib/backup

  redis:
    image: webhippie/redis:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REDIS_DATABASES=1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - redis:/var/lib/redis
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you get an error like that the problem is with the credentials especially with the password is very common to encounter this error.
Try using `docker-compose rm -v` and restart everything as the guide is saying.